# FileNotFoundException inside block where file.exists() is true

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, filenotfoundexception

I am experimenting with the Spring framework, running through some tutorials.

for some reason, the bean.xml is not found.

EDIT #5: As the Answer suggests, the file existing with the absolute path is irrelevant, when the method I am using is looking for the file in the Classpath. (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext())

**EDIT #1: PLEASE READ THE CODE: the file exists, and the failing code is inside the `if (xmlFile.exists())` block**

I have tried a relative path, with the file in the roo of the project, I have used an absolute path to the file in the project folder, and I have tried moving the Beans.xml to the root of several of my drives. The `File.exists()` call with the same path succeeds, but the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext()` constructor always fails...

My Puzzlement is why the FNF exception appears, then the File.exists() is true, and I only have that one fileName String

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT #2: I have now tried the same code on a linux machine. I get the same error exactly (with a Linux path ofc)

EDIT #3: I have now copied the file to target/classes and it runs. Ideally I would like it in resources... How do I go about doing that?

---

I am running Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE

Build Id: 201712210947

Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)

On Windows 10

---

Here is my ApplicationStart.java:

```
package com.example.pkg;

import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ApplicationStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        String xmlFileName = "E:\\Beans.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(xmlFileName);
        if (xmlFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println(xmlFile.getAbsolutePath() + " exists - Running Spring code");
            ApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(xmlFileName);
            Point p = (Point) appCtx.getBean("ZeroPoint");
            System.out.println(p.getX());
            System.out.println(p.getY());
            Point p2 = (Point) appCtx.getBean("TenPoint");
            System.out.println(p2.getX());
            System.out.println(p2.getY());
        } else {
            System.err.println("File " + xmlFileName + " does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

My Point.java

```
package com.example.pkg;

public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

---

My Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="ZeroPoint" class="com.example.pkg.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="TenPoint" class="com.example.pkg.Point">
        <property name="x" value="10" />
        <property name="y" value="10" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

Output of "run as java application":

```
Working Directory = C:\Users\jonas\Documents\workspaces\sts_test\artifact
C:\Users\jonas\Documents\workspaces\sts_test\artifact\Beans.xml exists - Running Spring code
dec. 24, 2017 2:36:08 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@137e0d2: startup date [Sun Dec 24 14:36:08 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
dec. 24, 2017 2:36:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:521)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.example.pkg.ApplicationStart.main(ApplicationStart.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 13 more
```

EDIT #4:

Working code. Putting the file in /src/main/resources and running the below works for me:

```
package com.example.pkg;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class ApplicationStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        String xmlFileName = "Beans.xml";

        //System.out.println(xmlFile.getAbsolutePath() + " exists - Running Spring code");
        ApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(xmlFileName);
        Point p = (Point) appCtx.getBean("ZeroPoint");
        System.out.println(p.getX());
        System.out.println(p.getY());
        Point p2 = (Point) appCtx.getBean("TenPoint");
        System.out.println(p2.getX());
        System.out.println(p2.getY());

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is located here: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`...

Comment: If you read the code, you will see that I actually check for the file existing to enter the block which fails

Comment: But the fact that the E:\Beans.xml file exists is irrelevant. The ClassPathXmlApplicationContext constructor doesn't expects a file path. It expects a classpath resource location (as the javadoc, the class name and the error message all indicate). https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext-java.lang.String...-

Comment: So how Do I specify the location? afaict I have done exactly the same as the course I am taking... I have now copied the file to target/classes and it runs. ideally I would like it in resources...

Comment: Put it where your build procedure would find it and copy it to the classes. In a Maven/gradle project, it would be in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use that `E:\beans.xml`, try using: [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html).

Simply replace your `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` with this class.

If you want to put it in resources folder then instead of passing the full path simply use:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml")
```

Comment: I would like to put it in `src/main/resources`

Comment: And for some reason that works. I have spent hours on this... and was sure that I had tried that. I mut have been a level above it.